# .htaccess file acting strangely and not working with lowercase

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The entire contents of my .htaccess file currently look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule     ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1      [NC]
```

This should replace all urls that look like http://example.com/folder/ with http://example.com/index.php?page=folder

This works fine if I use http://example.com/FOLDER/, but not when I use http://example.com/folder/ - I simply get a 404 error saying that the folder doesn't exist

This shouldn't happen, due to the NC (non-case-sensitive) flag, as far as I'm aware. I've also tried replacing the [a-z] section of the regex with [A-Z], [a-zA-Z] etc, all to no avail

Any solutions or shoves in the right direction would be gratefully received :-)

Comment: This sounds weird. I think it is forwarded all the time to `index.php` which is throwing a 404 depending on its code logic. Otherwise, if this is all your htaccess code, it is impossible that `/FOLDER/` does match while `/folder/` does not with `[a-z]+` pattern (even with `NC` flag)

Comment: Can you check the apache error log as well?

Comment: I moved the code across from my Web hosting to my VPS, and it works fine there, so I assume that it's just some weird configuration that the Web hosting company have going on

Comment: yeah, I tried it also and it worked fine. Try breaking the htaccess file to get a 500 error, just to make sure you are overriding the main file.

Comment: `^(\w+)/?$ index.php?page=$1` may work. Never seen that with `Mod Rewrite` before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may just have been an issue with the setup that my web hosting was using - I've permanently moved the entire site across to my VPS now, where it works fine - many thanks to the people who offered suggestions :-)